# buildToolsVersion is not specified

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting "Error: buildToolsVersion is not specified"
I've seen many people get this error but it has either been due to buildtooslversion not being specified in the module build.gradle or apply plugin being in the top level.

Top level build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    dependencies {
    }
```

Module build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.tst.test_app"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 28
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':test_app_lib')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It's been a year since I touched this code.  I previously built ok.  I updated android studio and SDKs and switch to target SDK28.  That's pretty much all I changed.

Comment: open project setting and check the build tool version, select any if it is empty

Answer (score 2):

add `google()` above `jcenter()` inside

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: This was not the cause of the error message but after fixing the error, I got another error.  Adding "google()" fixed the final error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to say which build tools are you using when you are using Android Pie

You only need to have something like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.app"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 0
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

And please update your dependencies from compile to implementation, like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

If your minSdkVersion is currently below 14, you will need to set it to 14 or higher. This is a limitation introduced in 26.

Comment: I still get the error message if I remove buildtoolsversion.  I tried older SDKs like 25 or 27 and still get the same error.

Comment: Please check the extra response @shizhen put, maybe that can help you add the google and jcenter repositories, In the gradle of all the project the small one

Answer (score 0):

It ended up that buildToolsVersion was not specified in the LIBRARY (test_app_lib).  When I added that, the error went away